# NullPointerException On a Calling a Function

Tags: java, java-me, nullpointerexception

I'm building a program that gets the value of a `TextField`, concatenate with some other `Strings` and then display them on a `TextBox` when the `ScreenCommand` is clicked, the problem is that it's calling a `NullPointerException`. My code is like this(of course it has a lot more stuff):

```
/* .... */
        } else if (command == submitCommand) {
            FirstPart();
            // write pre-action user code here
            switchDisplayable(null, getTextBox3());
            // write post-action user code here
        }
/* .... */

public void FirstPart() {
    String test = null;
    test = "tst" + textField.getString() + "test";
    textBox3.setString(test);
}
/* .... */
```

And I get this when I click the menu:

```
TRACE: <at java.lang.NullPointerException:   0>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
        at mp.releaser.MPReleaser.FirstPart(MPReleaser.java:535)
        at mp.releaser.MPReleaser.commandAction(MPReleaser.java:128)
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$ChameleonTunnel.callScreenListener(), bci=46
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.processCommand(), bci=74
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.commandSelected(), bci=11
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.MenuLayer.pointerInput(), bci=188
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.CWindow.pointerInput(), bci=88
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayEventConsumerImpl.handlePointerEvent(), bci=19
        at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=296
        at com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=179
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

What should I do to correct this?

*PS: Netbeans should have a `NullPointerException` corrector tool :P*

Comment: Is that code above `FirstPart`'s definition part of the `run` method? Which is line 680? What is the value of `textField`?

Comment: *My Ruby knowledge makes my mind blow every time I try Java*. Java needs to be more like Ruby for managing their variables :/

Comment: there's no chance that will happen.  You only get 3 wishes - so don't waste them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `FirstPart` method, the only thing I can imagine is that `textField` is `null` or `textBox3` is `null`. Are you sure it isn't `null`?

If I'm completely missing the point of your question, I apologize.

EDIT: Thank you, StriplingWarrior!

Comment: Both are `null`, but when I send the string, the `TextField` isn't `null` anymore and `TextBox` will receive a value, so they aren't `null` after that point

Comment: `setString` is an instance method. It can't be called on a `null` object. The same applies for `getString`.

Comment: I've set text for both of them before the click and I still get the `NullPointerException` :/

Comment: Are you able to step through the code? If not, could you manually throw your own exception if either of those members are `null`?

Comment: I just spotted that the problematic line is: `textBox3.setString(test);`, but I don't know what is wrong :/

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your application, I can't say why `textBox3` is `null`. Is it actually a field in your UI?

Comment: Yeah, just a field on my J2ME UI

Answer (score 1):

The only place a `NullPointer` can occur here is `textField.getString()` method or `textBox3`.  Debug there.